# JAX-WS Decorator

Tags: jax-ws, cdi, decorator

I have implemented interface annotated with @WebService and implemented it by class which is also annotated with @WebService(endpointInterface="..package.interface").
Everything works fine.

Now, I wanted to decorate this web service, so I implemented class which I annotated with @Decorator and done as advised in JavaEE tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv-examples005.htm#GKPAX).
I also included this decorator in beans.xml.

Decorator method does not get called whichever combination of annotations I try, e.g. @WebService on decorator class...

Am I missing something from architectural side or is there any rule about web service decoration?

Just to point out, I've found examples of JAX-RS services being decorated, on the web.

Here is my code:

```
@WebService
public interface IAppointer {
    String requestAppointment(AppointmentRequest request)
            throws AppointmentRequestValidationException, AppointmentException;
}

@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "appointment.services.IAppointer")
public class Appointer implements IAppointer {
   public String requestAppointment(AppointmentRequest request)
            throws AppointmentRequestValidationException, AppointmentException {}
}

@Decorator
@WebService(endpointInterface = "appointment.services.IAppointer")
public class AppointmentValidationDecorator implements IAppointer {

    @Inject
    @Delegate
    private IAppointer appointer;

    @Override
    public String requestAppointment(AppointmentRequest request)
            throws AppointmentRequestValidationException, AppointmentException {}
}
```

**TO ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION**

A solution is to place the `@Local` annotation on the interface and then to place `@Local(IAppointer.class)` on the decorated class. Somehow, EJB container creates a new interface for the web service bean although `@WebService` designates its interface. This way, we specify which local interface EJB container should use for this bean.

Comment: Show us your code - both, web service and the decorator.

Comment: @Siliarus Just to add, Appointer has to be stateless EJB.

Comment: I don't think your decorator should be `@WebService` (don't know about `IAppointer` either). But do try activating your decorator via `@Priority(number)` annotation instead of in `beans.xml` (but keep `beans.xml`), that might have an influence depending on deployment structure. Besides that you can also try adding `@Any` to your `@Delegate` injection point but that shouldn't change a thing unless you are using some qualifiers which your sample doesn't show.

Comment: @Siliarus From documentation: "The javax.jws.WebService annotation marks a Java class or interface as being a web
service. If used directly on the class, the annotation processor of the
container will generate the interface". This means that without specifying which interface this WebInterface should be bound to, I cannot apply decorator pattern since I cannot extend generated interface. Btw, I've tried all the combinations that you suggested.